# First steps at Nextjs are a mess

Tags: reactjs, next.js, module, frameworks

After running "npx create-next-app@latest --experimental-app  " I download all the files and get everything ready to start coding an app. The thing is, when I run "npm run dev" I get compiling errors with some modules, specifically the ones from google font.

"error - node_modules/@next/font/google/index.js (15:6) @ eval
error - Error: @next/font/google failed to run or is incorrectly configured.
If you just installed `@next/font`, please try restarting `next dev` and resaving your file."

I'm new to this framework and if I havent touched anything I should be seeing the next.js screen when running the app on localhost, right?

Any ideas as to why this is happening? And thanks in advance

Ill be leaving here my package.json here

```
"version": "0.1.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "incompilable",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "dependencies": {
        "@next/font": "13.1.6",
        "@types/node": "18.11.18",
        "@types/react": "18.0.27",
        "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
        "eslint": "8.33.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "13.1.6",
        "next": "13.1.6",
        "nvm": "^0.0.4",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0",
        "typescript": "4.9.4",
        "webpack": "^5.75.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "standard": "^17.0.0"
```

I tried  updating every necessary resource that next js uses. I was expecting to see that the app is running without compiling issues, but my best guess is that it has something to do with my Linux distro.

Answer (score 1):

You can reinstall NPM Modules using this command:

```
npm i -f
```

After that, start development server using `npm run dev` command.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues are creating the app in a **Powershell** Terminal but then trying to run it (by "mistake") from a **WSL** terminal (Ubuntu) .

Reinstalling the packages didn't help but staying **consistent** with which terminal I was using helped.

I didn't investigate further but I suspect that has to do with Powershell being case-(in)sensitive in some folders (there's now a possibility of enabling or disabling case sensitivity on some Windows folders).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was removing `.next` folder from the root of the project. This folder is used for local builds of NextJs. After removing that folder `npm run dev` successfully built the project